# laravel 5.0 change date time mysql language from English to Arabic using Carbon setLocale() function

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I have an object come from database and this object has property creation date which is date time format i want to change language of this property from English to Arabic in format "j-F,Y"

```
<?php 
      \Carbon\Carbon::setLocale('ar');
      $date = \Carbon\Carbon::setLocale('ar')->createFromDate("j-F,Y",$item->creation_date);
      echo $date->diffForHumans();
                             ?>
```

when i use this code the error is

Call to a member function createFromDate() on a non-object

as the function setLocale('ar') return Null value

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use `setLocale()` again.

```
\Carbon\Carbon::setLocale('ar');
$date = \Carbon::createFromDate('j-F, Y', $item->creation_date);
echo $date->diffForHumans();
```

Also if you're planning to use Arabic format, consider adding `Carbon::setLocale()` into `boot()` method of application provider (`app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php`).

Comment: i want to set locale in dynamic way and why adding Carbon::setLocale() into boot() method of application provider (app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php).

Comment: If dynamic (just for this property) - this step is not required.

Comment: Add `setlocale(LC_TIME, 'LANGUAGE_CODE');` (for example 'ar-XX' - you must choose which one) before `Carbon::setLocale()`